# Python - Annotate values where True (and use other value)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe of values which I am using to plot a scatter/line graph with confidence intervals:

The dataframe (sqlDF2) is like this:

```
Statu   Total   Outside   Success   Pred   Upper95    Lower95      Upper99    Lower99
Org                             
A        391    True       38    0.35064  0.398903   0.302377    0.423034    0.278245
B        360    False       30    0.343464 0.393519   0.293408    0.418546    0.268381
C        271    False       29    0.319606 0.37626    0.262951    0.404587    0.234624
D        247    True       22    0.312089 0.371053   0.253125    0.400535    0.223643
...
```

My code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize Figure and Axes object
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))

# Load in the data
data = sqlDf2

y = data['Success'].values
x = data['Total'].values
up95 = (data['Upper95'].values)*100
low95 = (data['Lower95'].values)*100
up99 = (data['Upper99'].values)*100
low99 = (data['Lower99'].values)*100
middleLine = (data['Pred'].values)*100
holdOrg = sqlDf2.index.tolist()



# Create plot
sns.regplot(x="Total", y="Success", data=data,fit_reg=False, ax=ax)
plt.plot(x,up95, linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,low95, linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,up99, linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,low99, linewidth=2)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.margins(x=0)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

I am trying to annotate the values in the scatter plot ONLY when the column `'Outside'` is `True`. At the moment every point is being annotated:

[image]

I also want the value annotated to not be `x` or `y`, but instead the value from 'holdOrg'.

Is this easy to do?

Comment: This problem seems completely independent on the data in `sqlDf2`. So please do annoy people by dropping some irrelevant data. See [mcve].

Comment: Thank you. I have removed large sections of code.

Comment: Noo, that is for sure not useful. You should point out what you have tried using a [mcve].

Comment: Oh I see. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have three lists, `x,y,z` you can label the points at positions given by `x` and `y` with labels in `z` by looping over those three lists.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
z = ["A","B","C"]
#annotation
for i,j, label in zip(x,y,z):
    ax.annotate(label,xy=(i,j))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just going to check this works :)

Comment: Hey, it is working except it is putting the FULL list of Z for each value. Is that me messing up?

Comment: I just reproduced it with just the code from your example, and it is still putting ['A', 'B', 'C'] for each label. Any idea? thank you very much

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Working perfectly!